# can't access restricted pages with jsoup after login

Tags: jsoup

i'm trying to to scrap data from https://dcs3.noaa.gov but with some problems.
At the moment i can login to the page and get the cookies but when i try to access to a restricted page i get the login page.

Here is my code:

```
package jsouptelemetrica;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Jsouptelemetrica {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try {

        Map<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Connection.Response loginRes = Jsoup.connect("https://dcs3.noaa.gov/ACCOUNT/Login")
                                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0")
                                            .execute();
        cookies.putAll(loginRes.cookies());
        loginRes = Jsoup.connect("https://dcs3.noaa.gov/ACCOUNT/Login")
                           .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0")
                           .data("__RequestVerificationToken", cookies.get("__RequestVerificationToken"),
                                   "Email", "my-email",
                                 "Password", "super secret password")
                            //this is the same cookie you used for url2!
                           .method(Method.POST)
                           .followRedirects(true)
                           .cookies(cookies)
                           .execute();
                           //System.out.println(loginRes.body());
                           cookies.putAll(loginRes.cookies());
    Document doc  = Jsoup.connect("https://dcs3.noaa.gov/Messages/List").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36")
                                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0")
                                        .cookies(cookies)
                                        .referrer("https://dcs3.noaa.gov/ACCOUNT/Login")
                                        .method(Method.GET)
                                        .data("Grid-sort","")
                                        .data("Grid-page","1")
                                        .data("Grid-pageSize","20")
                                        .data("Grid-group","")
                                        .data("Grid-filter","")
                                        .get();

    //Document doc = Resp1.parse();  
    cookies.putAll(loginRes.cookies());
    System.out.println(doc.toString());
    }catch(Exception e){

        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Any help would we appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you know if your login was successfull??

Comment: because after i try to login a ASP.NET_SessionId cookie appears

Comment: I have just checked and can verify that the cookies appears for me even after a failed login

Comment: So I think your problem here is that you are not logging in successfully

Comment: Thank you Joel, i didnt try it

Answer (score 0):

As Joel Min says the problem was with the auth